# build mysql driver for Necessitas (qt-android)

Tags: mysql, build, cmake, header-files, qt-necessitas

I´m trying to build a mysql driver to use it in a qt-android app.
Now everything seems to be clear but there is a inconsistency in my head.
While i´m compiling the mysql-connector-c source ( 6.0.2 ) cmake got a lot of missing header files.
Thats ok, but my problem is where to get these headers? or can I just use my gcc headers?

Thank you in advance!

Link to the guide I Worked with: http://qa-android.com/comp-lib-qt-android/2012-11/pdfNpp3xMBVQQ.pdf

Comment: I think the headers in cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++ differ to the regular gcc headers?!

Comment: (you all welcome to edit my question! the guys who build opencv maybe got comparable issues)

Comment: Could you by the way show us the error message?

Comment: Thank you making efforts.  It is not that hard problem cmake only missing some header files. like "crypt.h not found" \n "fpu/control.h not found" these errors are easiely avoidable... but my problem is. Can I use my standard gnu (i386-gnu-linux) header files or have i search for android-ndk (what ever) spezific header files?